# How to find the max length of a string in a list of object (Python)

Tags: python

```
class XYZ:

    def __init__(self, name, score):
        self.name = name
        self.score = score


l = []     # l is the list of objects

l.append(XYZ('Anmol', 10))
l.append(XYZ('Andrew', 200))
l.append(XYZ('Johnson', 3000))
```

In the above code l is the list of object containing three objects, every object has a name (string) and a score (integer), so how can i find out what is the maximum length of the name in that list of object

In our program, the maximum length of name is for the name of Johnson, it's length is 7. So the program should give output as 7. How to do it?

Comment: `max(len(xyz.name) for xyz in l)`

Answer (score 7):

With [`list comprehension`](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions), and without a `lambda`, it would look like this:

```
 result = max(len(x) for x in l)
```

Essentially, this does the following (it helps to break down list comprehensions from right-to-left):

1. `in l`: iterates over `l`
2. `for x`: assigns each element of `l` to the variable `x` during the iteration
3. `len(x)`: get the length of each variable `x` within the list `l`
4. `list comprehensions` put the output into a list format naturally, so at this point we have a list of all the lengths of strings, like:

   ```
   [5, 6, 7]
   ```
5. `max(...)`: simply gets the largest number from the list of lengths

Hopefully this explanation helps understand what is going on.

Answer (score 3):

```
longest_xyz = max(l, key=lambda item: len(item.name))
print("The length of the longest string is ", len(longest_xyz.name))
```

Answer (score 3):

This is one functional way:

```
from operator import attrgetter

result = max(map(len, map(attrgetter('name'), l)))

# 7
```

Answer (score 3):

This does not always apply, but if it is part of your class logic to compare based on the length of `name`, you can implement the special class methods `__lt__` and `__eq__`.

```
class XYZ:
    def __init__(self, name, score):
        self.name = name
        self.score = score

    def __lt__(self, other):
        return len(self.name) < len(other.name)

    def __eq__(self, other):
        return self.name == other.name and self.score == other.score
```

The result:

```
l = [XYZ('Anmol', 10), XYZ('Andrew', 200), XYZ('Johnson', 3000)]

max(l).name # 'Johnson'
```

Note that doing so will also specify a behaviour for comparison operators (`==`, `<` and `>`) aswell as for `sorted` for your class instances.